# How to edit image quality in homepage (Magento ver. 1.9.0.1)

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, image

I installed Magento ver. 1.9.0.1 Here the problem is the image in home page looks very bad. I know this question has been asked for many years. Nearly googled 2 days read posts regarding same issue, Bad Luck find no proper fixes.Is there any way to change the compression settings in backend, or is there any way to change optimization techniques without modifying core code. Here I attached the issue images for better reference.

- When product image is uploaded, magento compress images as base, thumbnail, small as per our selection.
- Image quality in home page is very disappointing (not sure what type: base or thumbnail or small)
- Is there any way to change the compression technique?

**This is HOME PAGE**

[image: It looks very bad]

**This is CATEGORY PAGE**

[image: It looks fine]

**This is PRODUCT PAGE**

[image: It also looks fine]

Image 1 is very bad.
Images 2&3 are good.

Answer (score 1):

Magento uses GD to shrink images and GD is not that great. It is better to use ImageMagick, but this is not implemented out of the box.

You can try https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Perfect_Watermarks which implements ImageMagick - and of course you need the ImageMagick lib.

Good luck!

Comment: Already saw this fix, but the problem is "In some case the use of imagemagick will produce very high load". It may not be the best option. Is there any other alternative to this problem.

Comment: Not that I know

Comment: Hi all,I found the solution. Just edit in CMS page (HOME PAGE) to insert New Products instead of adding widget in CMS. Thanks all....